# Settings.Default.Upgrade() after assembly name changed

Tags: c#

For some reasons I had to change the assembly name(.exe). Since .net settings are saved using assembly name. Framework cannot find the proper .config file that usually exists in `[USER]/AppData/Local`, hence when calling the `Upgrade` on `Settings.Default` does no upgrade. Which is working as intended by Framework. But since the assembly Guid is same, is there any possible flag that allows to use a specific assembly name for checking the Settings file.

My solution is to rename the directories of Setting file before calling the Upgrade or manually reading the old .config file and update each setting. But its just a mess.

I'm using .net framework 2.0

Any help would be nice.
Thank you

Comment: Thats not what Upgrade is intended to do.  Your settings are saved to an obscure location which is determined by a hash of several things including Assembly based info.  When you changed the name, it changes the hash so the new version wont find the old.

Comment: True, but I need to get those old settings.

Comment: I am not sure NewAsm will even have the right to read from OldAsm path.  This kind of thing doesnt happen if you take charge and serialize your own list of settings.  You can store them in a common user folder and even share between a suite of apps

Comment: Thats exactly what I need to do, but I also need old values.

Comment: You could try to change the Asm name back, load the settings then convert them to a new list<settings> and serialize that to a logical path.  That might rescue them, but I am not sure VS will generate the same hash as before even with the old name.  Otherwise, *Measure Twice, Cut Once*